# Wpf - NavigationService.GoBack() and Listbox SelectionChanged Event

Tags: wpf, navigation, selectionchanged

In ADDPage.xaml page there i s a Back Button with the code  NavigationService.GoBack() to go back to the previous page.

Problem:

In the Listbox SelectionChanged Event of another page (SubPage.xaml)i am using the NavigationService.Navigate(new ADDPage(search));

When ever the page executes NavigationService.GoBack() of ADDPage.xaml page, the control moves to the Listbox SelectionChanged Event of SubPage.xaml and it loads the same page again. Is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I used Delegate to fix my problem.

SubPage.xaml.cs

```
public delegate void RefreshHandle(string message);

public partial class SubPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public static RefreshHandle RefreshCallback;

    void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string msg = "Test";
        RefreshCallback(msg);  
        NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        SubPage.RefreshCallback += new RefreshHandle(RefreshFn);
    }
    void RefreshFn(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```